# Change of the smallest positive eigenvalue after a rank-one update

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues

Given natural numbers $n,r,R\in\mathbb{N}$ with $r,R\le n$, let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times r}$ and $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times R}$ be two matrices with full column rank and let $c\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
Denote by $\lambda_{\mathrm{min}^\star}(X)$ the smallest positive eigenvalue of $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.
Is it true that
$$
\lambda_{\mathrm{min}^\star}(AA^\intercal + BB^\intercal + cc^\intercal)
- \lambda_{\mathrm{min}^\star}(AA^\intercal + BB^\intercal)
\le \lambda_{\mathrm{min}^\star}(AA^\intercal + cc^\intercal)
- \lambda_{\mathrm{min}^\star}(AA^\intercal) ?
$$
If it is not true, are there conditions on $A$, $B$ and $c$ such that it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true, try
$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right),\;\;c=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),$$
$$\lambda_{\mathrm{min}^\star}(AA^\intercal + BB^\intercal + cc^\intercal)
- \lambda_{\mathrm{min}^\star}(AA^\intercal + BB^\intercal)=6-5=1,$$
$$\lambda_{\mathrm{min}^\star}(AA^\intercal + cc^\intercal)
- \lambda_{\mathrm{min}^\star}(AA^\intercal)=1-1=0.$$